# How to get optimal drive performance for a DB on SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Ed.?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, table-partitioning

So I am pretty green when it comes to hardware configurations.

I just asked a coworker and he said we're using RAID 60 (I assume is the same as RAID 6+0).

I am doing some tests on a large table (1 billion rows), and setup a different partition for each day of data.  From what I understand I would want to ideally put each partition on a separate filegroup and each filegroup would get its own dedicated disk.

Am I right that creating "virtual" drives for each FG is not going to make a difference since all of the storage is coming off of a RAID 60 "device"?

Is there anything  I can do to improve disk performance when creating an index on a table of this size?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right that creating "virtual" drives for each FG is not going to make a difference since all of the storage is coming off of a RAID 60 "device"?

Yes you are absolutely right. That data is already striped all over that array.

> Is there anything I can do to improve disk performance when creating an index on a table of this size?

Unless you have control over the hardware and RAID setup, there is nothing you can do. `CREATE INDEX` will run in parallel with Enterprise Ed but that is on by [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189329.aspx) anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jack, it was not as bad as I anticipated, finishing in 1 hour, over 1 billion records, for 6 columns.